# Can WebSocket do 2 way communication where one is running for ever?

Tags: php, node.js, websocket

I have a application that interacts with a telephony system. The telephony system has a REST API where I connect to using my PHP App to handle interaction (make, hold, mute calls....)

I am considering the use of a WebSocket to better manage my requests and wonder if it works. In order to user a WebSocket, I will need to be able to communicate with the API using WebSocket in 2 ways.

**1. A user send a command to the WebSocket.**

When a user want to make a phone call, then he/she types a number then press "dial" button. The dial button will need to send a command to the WebSocket with some info like "phone number and a dial command". The WebSocket will take that request and initiate a request to the API service to handle the command.

**2. WebSocket does an infinite loop to check the queue's queue and send it to the client.**

Additionally, when a connection is established between the client and the WebSocket, the WebSocket will need make a call to the API service **every second** to check a queue. This queue will let the client know if they are on the phone, or if the have an inbound call, or if the active call is on mute....

**Question:** Can the WebSocket handle both scenarios 1 & 2? can the user still sends command to the API at the same time the WebSocket keeps checking the queue for messages?

Comment: WebSockets is a bi-directional communication protocol, so yes, it can do what you need. Your client can send commands to the server and it can receive messages. However, since you already use sockets - why would you need to check every second if there are messages in the queue? Is it not better that your server notifies the client *when* there are messages in the queue? You're using node and web sockets, you can come up with advanced systems using the two technologies - no need for the old http polling tricks.

Comment: @N.B. every time messages are read in the API, they are permanently deleted from the API. I have to keep these messages in a session in the WebSocket where I know the last message "current status." For example, if I get a message stating that the user is on the phone with 800-123-8888, then this message will never be in the API service again. But I have to keep it in the WebSocket session so when the user navigates to a different page they still know the current status "on phone/on mute..." Every time the page is refreshed the last message will need to be sent to the client.

Comment: Since we can't see how you constructed your site and how it all works, it's difficult to get into your mindset. Anyway, do think about what I said - you don't have to poll. Now, whether you decide polling is easier or not, that's up to you. Important thing to remember is that WebSockets is not a request-reply protocol like HTTP. You can send a message and get no response, or receive a message from the server without asking for one in the first place. That's what makes WebSockets awesome.

Comment: @N.B. thank you for your feedback. The only issue that I have is that the user must know their current status on every page load. I am not sure if I am doing this correctly or not, but my approach will means the WebSocket will always have a message to send back. The message will be a json string. When the client reads it, the "phone interface" is updated on the page load or every time a message is received. ("phone interface", shows the current status....) Since the API deletes the messages from the queue do you see any better way of doing this other than keeping the last status in a session?

Comment: So if you are doing full page reloads, why can't you deliver a JSON string at that point? Why must it be websocket? Also, websockets are great for single page apps (page reloads are ajaxed, there's no actual full page reload).

Comment: Currently, I am doing an ajax request using `$.ajax` in a `setInterval()` function. The $.ajax calls a file called `hander.php`. This file does calls the API updates a session then the session is read and the client receives the final message as json. But the problem is that it works for about 2 hours before my web server crashes.